# .NET MVC reusable string snippets / shortcodes, not classes #NOOB

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, vbscript

I'm migrating from Classic ASP/VbScript to ASP.NET MVC and am still new at .NET concepts.  I want to call a handful of misc functions (which are technically *methods* as I understand them) throughout my [web-based] application that will write directly to the browser in that location in my View.

I think I need to make these into string methods of a class and instantiate that class as public somewhere that is available to the View, so:

```
// this is my class which will be chock-full of misc methods I can use as shortcodes
namespace MyApp.ShortCodes {
    public class RenderMisc {
            public string PrivacyPolicy {
                return "<div id='privacy'><strong>This is the privacy policy.</strong></div>";
            }
            public string Copyright() {
                return "<div id='copy'><strong>Copyright " + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + ".</strong></div>";
            }
            public string HamburgerRecipe {
                return "<div id='recipe'><strong>Use Hamburgers and Buns.  Beans are a nice side.</strong></div>";
            }
        }
}
```

Then in my Views I would have:

```
// instantiate class
@{MyApp.ShortCodes.RenderMisc m = MyApp.ShortCodes.RenderMisc();}
<html>
<p>bla bla this is my HTML code bla bla here is a recipe you will like:</p>
@Html.Raw(m.HamburgerRecipe())
<p>Thanks for looking!</p>
<p>Don't steal this cause @Html.Raw(m.PrivacyPolicy()) and @Html.Raw(m.Copyright())!</p>
</html>
```

Ok so I know conceptually this is dumb, but you see what I am trying to do?  In ASP/VB this would be represented as:

```
Function PrivacyPolicy()
    Response.Write "<div id='privacy'><strong>This is the privacy policy.</strong></div>"
End Function
Function Copyright()
    Response.Write "<div id='copy'><strong>Copyright " + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + ".</strong></div>"
End Function
Function HamburgerRecipe()
    Response.Write "<div id='recipe'><strong>Use Hamburgers and Buns.  Beans are a nice side.</strong></div>"
End Function
```

Then in my normal code basically anywhere on any page I would have:

```
<html>
<p>bla bla this is my HTML code bla bla here is a recipe you will like:</p>
<% Call HamburgerRecipe() %>
<p>Thanks for looking!</p>
<p>Don't steal this cause  <% Call PrivacyPolicy() %> and <% Call Copyright() %>!</p>
</html>
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Why not just create some partial views containing the html you want to render and use `@Html.Partial("_MyPartial")` in the view

Comment: Because I hadn't considered that yet, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
namespace MyApp
{
  namespace ShortCodes 
  {
    public static class RenderMisc 
    {
      public readonly string PrivacyPolicy = 
        "<div id='privacy'><strong>This is the privacy policy.</strong></div>";

      public string GenerateCopyright() 
      {
        return "<div id='copy'><strong>Copyright " 
          + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() 
          + ".</strong></div>";
      }

      public reaonly string HamburgerRecipe =
        "<div id='recipe'><strong>Use Hamburgers and Buns.  Beans are a nice side.</strong></div>";            
    }
  }
}
```

Not that I endorse the design.

Comment: Thanks; being a noob what design would you recommend to accomplish this?  I'm not married to my concept it's just what I can relate to (VB).  I'm hungry to learn best practices.